# Ayuda con Arduino via Serial

Tags: arduino

Tengo un Arduino que lo utilizo para mover unos servos. El Arduino tiene el siguiente código:

```
#include<Servo.h>

//Creamos los objetos servo
Servo servo;
Servo servo2;
Servo servo3;
Servo servo4;

int enviado; //Aqui enviamos el numero completo
int num; //Numero del servo
int posicion; //Posicion del servo

void setup()
{
  //Inicializamos los Servos
  servo.attach(9);
  servo2.attach(10);
  servo3.attach(11);
  servo4.attach(6);

  //Inicializamos la comunicacion por Serial
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop()
{
  if(Serial.available() >= 1)
  {
    /*
    1- Leer un numero entero por serial
    2- Calculamos su modulo por 10 (sera el numero del motor)
    3- Dividir el entero inicial por 10
    4- Lo que quede, sera la posicion del motor
    */
    enviado = Serial.parseInt();
    num = enviado%10;
    enviado = enviado/10;
    posicion = enviado;

    //Hora de mover los servos!
    if(num == 1)
    {
      servo.write(posicion);
    }
    else if(num == 2)
    {
      servo2.write(posicion);
    }
    else if(num == 3)
    {
      servo3.write(posicion);
    }
    else if(num == 4)
    {
      servo4.write(posicion);
    }
  }

}
```

El problema que tengo es que yo al enviar la información necesaria para que el servo que yo quiera se mueva a donde yo quiera hay un delay entre que pulso el entre y se mueve el servo.

No se si es que el Arduino tarda en calcular lo que yo le mando para saber lo que debe hacer o si estoy haciendo yo algo mal.

Comment: Has intentado colocar el `delay` o `wait`, porque se esta ejecutando millones de veces por segundo.

Comment: No, no le he probado, pero eso influye en el delay?

Comment: No lo sé pero de que vas a dañar algo si no lo pones, es un hecho

Comment: @GabrielJeremyRodriguezRiver , tal y como pongo en mi respuesta siempre hay un intervalo de espera de 1 sg entre iteración e iteración si no se reciben datos. Además, un arduino no se va a dañar o quemar ni por tener un bucle infinito. Como mucho aumentará su consumo, reduciendo la autonomía si usas pilas o baterías.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema que sufres es debido a que la función [`Serial.parseInt()`](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/ParseInt) espera a recibir un carácter delimitador que finalice el número entero o bien espera a que finalice el tiempo máximo de espera definido por defecto a 1 segundo en [`Serial.SetTimeout()`](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Serial/SetTimeout):

> Parsing stops when no characters have been read for a configurable time-out value, or a non-digit is read

Lo que significa que:

> El análisis finaliza cuando no se han leído caracteres durante un tiempo configurable, o se lee un carácter que no es un dígito

Por lo que cuando pulsas un número la función espera a que envíes algo que termine el número (por ejemplo un retorno del carro, un espacio o un delimitador cualquiera). En caso contrario espera durante 1000 ms hasta dar por finalizada la entrada del número entero.

Te recomiendo enviar un delimitador junto con el número a través del puerto serie. Así evitarás [el problema que estás sufriendo en esta otra pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/111272/problemas-al-mover-motores-dc).