# Problemas al mover motores DC

Tags: python, arduino

Tengo una Raspberry Pi con un servidor web donde hay un joystick. He programado un script en python que se encarga de traducir la posición del joystick a la velocidad que tienen que tener los motores DC para que el coche gire como indica el joystick. Este es el script:

```
#! /usr/bin/python

import cgi, cgitb
import socket
cgitb.enable()

socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
form = cgi.FieldStorage()
x = float(form.getvalue('grados'))
y = float(form.getvalue('distancia'))

if 0 <= x and x <= 90:
        derecha = int(round((y/100)*((2*x/90)-1)*255))
        izquierda = int(round((y/100)*255))
        print(derecha, izquierda)
        sent = socket.sendto(str(derecha) + "5", ('127.0.0.1', 31113))
        sent = socket.sendto(str(izquierda) + "6", ('127.0.0.1', 31113))
if 90 < x and x <= 180:
        derecha = int(round((y/100)*255))
        izquierda = int(round(((-2*(x-90)/90)+1)*255))
        print(derecha, izquierda)
        sent = socket.sendto(str(derecha) + "5", ('127.0.0.1', 31113))
        sent = socket.sendto(str(izquierda) + "6", ('127.0.0.1', 31113))
if 180 < x and x <= 270:
        derecha = int(round((y/100)*((-2*(x-180)/90)+1)*255))
        izquierda = int(round((y/100)*-255))
        print(derecha, izquierda)
        sent = socket.sendto(str(derecha) + "5", ('127.0.0.1', 31113))
        sent = socket.sendto(str(izquierda) + "6", ('127.0.0.1', 31113))
if 270 < x and x <= 270:
        derecha = int(round((y/100)*-255))
        izquierda = int(round((y/100)*((2*(x-270)/90)-1)*255))
        print(derecha, izquierda)
        sent = socket.sendto(str(derecha) + "5", ('127.0.0.1', 31113))
        sent = socket.sendto(str(izquierda) + "6", ('127.0.0.1', 31113))
```

En el script creo que no hay fallos. Me dice un valor entre -255 o 255 que indica la velocidad. El signo se encarga de indicar si las ruedas van hacia delante o hacia detrás. Detrás de este numero se añado un 5 (motor derecha) o un 6 (motor izquierda) para poder diferenciarlos mas tarde en el Arduino.

El código Arduino creo que esta bien escrito porque si envio yo los datos a mano va todo perfectamente pero si lo hace el joystick no va bien. Es este (hay unas cosas de unos servos que controlo con el mismo Arduino pero no tiene nada que ver):

```
#include<Servo.h>

//Creamos los objetos servo
Servo servo;
Servo servo2;
Servo servo3;
Servo servo4;

int DV = 5;
int DA = 12;
int DR = 8;
int IV = 4;
int IA = 7;
int IR = 3;
int enviado; //Aqui enviamos el numero completo
int num; //Numero del servo
int posicion; //Posicion del servo

void setup()
{
  //Inicializamos los Servos
  servo.attach(9);
  servo2.attach(10);
  servo3.attach(11);
  servo4.attach(6);

  pinMode (DV, OUTPUT);
  pinMode (DA, OUTPUT);
  pinMode (DR, OUTPUT);
  pinMode (IV, OUTPUT);
  pinMode (IA, OUTPUT);
  pinMode (IR, OUTPUT);
  //Inicializamos la comunicacion por Serial
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop()
{
    /*
    1- Leer un numero entero por serial
    2- Calculamos su modulo por 10 (sera el numero del motor)
    3- Dividir el entero inicial por 10
    4- Lo que quede, sera la posicion del motor
    */
    enviado = Serial.parseInt();
    num = enviado%10;
    enviado = enviado/10;
    posicion = enviado;

    //Hora de mover los servos!
    if(num == 1)
    {
      servo.write(posicion);
    }
    else if(num == 2)
    {
      servo2.write(posicion);
    }
    else if(num == 3)
    {
      servo3.write(posicion);
    }
    else if(num == 4)
    {
      servo4.write(posicion);
    }
    else if(num == 5 || num == -5)
    {
      if (posicion > 0)
      {
        digitalWrite(DA, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(DR, LOW);
        analogWrite(DV, posicion);
      }
      if (posicion == 0)
      {
        analogWrite(DV, 0);
      }
      if (posicion < 0)
      {
        digitalWrite(DA, LOW);
        digitalWrite(DR, HIGH);
        analogWrite(DV, abs(posicion));
      }
    }
    else if(num == 6 || num == -6)
    {
      if (posicion > 0)
      {
        digitalWrite(IA, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(IR, LOW);
        analogWrite(IV, posicion);
      }
      if (posicion == 0)
      {
        analogWrite(IV, 0);
      }
      if (posicion < 0)
      {
        digitalWrite(IA, LOW);
        digitalWrite(IR, HIGH);
        analogWrite(IV,abs(posicion));
      }
    }
}
```

Creo que el error esta en que los motores van con delay al moverse entonces se crea una cola y no se mueve como debería. Lo que no entiendo es porque hay delay cuando yo no lo he programado.

EDIT: Consigo hace que el motor de la derecha se muevan enviando yo aparte los valores, con el script se mueven de forma aleatoria. El de la izquierda no consigo controlando ni enviando los valores yo a mano ni usando el script con el que también se mueve de forma aleatoria.

EDIT2: Ya he solucionado lo del motor de la izquierda. Pensé que no tenia sentido que no fuera el de la izquierda y el de la derecha si y el problema es que las salidas estaban mal.

Comment: Falta el código HTML/JS del joystick para comprobar si estás saturando el puerto serie y/o el servidor UDP. Si una llamada aislada funciona correctamente y una secuencia de modificaciones es lo que agrega la latencia parece claro que se está formando una cola de peticiones en algún lado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es muy probable que estés sufriendo un efecto no deseado de enviar datos enteros sin ningún tipo de separador a través del puerto serie.

### Problema en la interpretación de los datos

Como puedes ver en la documentación de [Serial.parseInt](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/ParseInt):

> Parsing stops when no characters have been read for a configurable time-out value, or a non-digit is read

Lo que significa que:

> El análisis finaliza cuando no se han leído caracteres durante un tiempo configurable, o se lee un carácter que no es un dígito

Lo que estás sufriendo es el efecto de enviar por el puerto serie de manera continuada datos enteros que no pueden ser diferenciados unos de otros, por lo que sólo cuando hay una pausa de un segundo o más se analiza el contenido del número entero o agregas un nuevo signo negativo, etc.

**Ejemplo:**

Si envías en menos de un segundo los datos "543" (movimiento 54 al motor 3) y "1234" (movimiento 123 al motor 4) el código de arduino entenderá que has enviado "5431234" (movimiento 543123 al motor 4).

Eso explicaría por qué se te mueven de manera aparentemente aleatoria. Como ves "se ha comido" el movimiento del motor 3 y, sin embargo, ha llegado un movimiento corrupto al motor 4.

### Solución propuesta

En el siguiente código agrego un ";" al final de cada número para forzar el análisis de la cadena recibida por el puerto serie:

```
#! /usr/bin/python

import cgi, cgitb
import socket
cgitb.enable()

socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
form = cgi.FieldStorage()
x = float(form.getvalue('grados'))
y = float(form.getvalue('distancia'))

if 0 <= x and x <= 90:
        derecha = int(round((y/100)*((2*x/90)-1)*255))
        izquierda = int(round((y/100)*255))
        print(derecha, izquierda)
        sent = socket.sendto(str(derecha) + "5;", ('127.0.0.1', 31113))
        sent = socket.sendto(str(izquierda) + "6;", ('127.0.0.1', 31113))
if 90 < x and x <= 180:
        derecha = int(round((y/100)*255))
        izquierda = int(round(((-2*(x-90)/90)+1)*255))
        print(derecha, izquierda)
        sent = socket.sendto(str(derecha) + "5;", ('127.0.0.1', 31113))
        sent = socket.sendto(str(izquierda) + "6;", ('127.0.0.1', 31113))
if 180 < x and x <= 270:
        derecha = int(round((y/100)*((-2*(x-180)/90)+1)*255))
        izquierda = int(round((y/100)*-255))
        print(derecha, izquierda)
        sent = socket.sendto(str(derecha) + "5;", ('127.0.0.1', 31113))
        sent = socket.sendto(str(izquierda) + "6;", ('127.0.0.1', 31113))
if 270 < x and x <= 270:
        derecha = int(round((y/100)*-255))
        izquierda = int(round((y/100)*((2*(x-270)/90)-1)*255))
        print(derecha, izquierda)
        sent = socket.sendto(str(derecha) + "5;", ('127.0.0.1', 31113))
        sent = socket.sendto(str(izquierda) + "6;", ('127.0.0.1', 31113))
```

Answer (score 0):

Buenas tardes, prueba colocar delay(1) para estabilidad de arduino.

```
digitalWrite(DA, HIGH);
delay(1);
digitalWrite(DR, LOW);
delay(1);
analogWrite(DV, posicion);
delay(1);
```

Si puedes haz un volcado de los datos recibidos.

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67454/discussion-on-answer-by-gustavo-problemas-al-mover-motores-dc).

Comment: Si es una prueba antes de dar con la solución deberías redactar un comentario, no una respuesta.